# rails sunspot gem friendly SEO url's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sunspot, sunspot-solr

How does one get SEO friendly url's in sunspot?,

The method of search form is GET as suggested from the rails docs, but now i have a very long query string that looks terrible, is it possible to have it something like

```
/search/param1/bla/param2/bla
```

instead of the long

```
?search&param1=somevalue&param2=someval2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your search route to include the params.  Something like this within your routes.rb:

```
  match '/search/:param1/:param2' => 'search_controller#search_action', :as => :search_with_params, :via => :get
```

Then a user would visit:

`/search/value1/value2`

Which gives you params[:param1] and params[:param2] to access the values from the url.

If those 2 params are not required for all searches I believe you would also need a route just for the search action:

```
match '/search' => 'search_controller#search_aciton', :as => :search, :via => :get
```